# ThreeJS: creating multiple material-type objects conflicts with scene

Tags: typescript, three.js

I don't understand why when I add a star to the scene, every object in the scene changes its color to white, and the perspective of the objects was glitching as well. When I tried changing the `materialStar` to `new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial`, the rendering works fine. The problem seems to be multiple and conflicting material types for the objects, but I initialized the variables with different names, so I don't understand why that is the problem.

```
// TORUS
const geometry = new THREE.TorusGeometry(10, 3, 16, 100);
const materialTorus = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({color: 0xFF6347}); // Initializing the torus's material type
const torus = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, materialTorus);
scene.add(torus);
...
function addStar() {
  // STAR
  const geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(0.25, 24, 24);
  const materialStar = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({color: 0xffffff}); // Initializing the star's material type
  const star = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, materialStar);

  const [x, y, z] = Array(3).fill(null).map(() => THREE.MathUtils.randFloatSpread(100)); // Creating different stars' positions

  star.position.set(x,y,z);
  scene.add(star);
}
Array(200).fill(null).forEach(addStar); // Generating stars
```

[image: an image of scenes when the objects' material conflicts]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working option.

```css
body{
  overflow:hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script type="module">
import * as THREE from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/three@0.136.0";
import {OrbitControls} from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/three@0.136.0/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls";

let scene = new THREE.Scene();
let camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, innerWidth / innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.set(0, 20, 40);
let renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(innerWidth, innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

let controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

let light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1);
light.position.setScalar(1);
scene.add(light, new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 0.5));

scene.add(new THREE.GridHelper(100, 10));

// TORUS
const geometry = new THREE.TorusGeometry(10, 3, 16, 100);
const materialTorus = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({color: 0xFF6347});
const torus = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, materialTorus);
scene.add(torus);

// STARS
let starGeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(0.25, 24, 24);
let starMaterial = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({color: 0xffffff});
for(let i = 0; i < 100; i++){
  let star = new THREE.Mesh(starGeometry, starMaterial);
  star.position.random().subScalar(0.5).multiplyScalar(100);
  scene.add(star);
}

renderer.setAnimationLoop(() => {
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
});
</script>
```

PS Check the intensity of light(s) in your scene, possibly it's way too much.